# How to join single table multiple time on single column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables:

```
1. tbPatientEpisode (
    EpisodeIDP
    EpisodeNumber
    DoctorIDF
    PatientIDF
)

2. tbPatient (
    PatientIDP
    CitizenIDF
)

3. tbDoctor(
    DoctorIDP
    CitizenIDF
)

4. tbCitizen(
    CitizenIDP
    CitizenName
    City
    ContactNo
)
```

I want to query the tbPatientEpisode table obtaining the DoctorName and the PatientName in single a row, but PatientIDF and DoctorIDF point to tbCitizen.   So please help to join tbCitizen table twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this it works fine for you,

```
    Select pe.*, c1.CitizenName as PatientName, c2.CitizenName as DoctorName 
    from tbPatientEpisode pe
    join tbPatient p on pe.PatientIDF = p.PatientIDP
    join tbDoctor d on pe.DoctorIDF = d.DoctorIDP
    join tbCitizen c1 on p.CitizenIDF = c1.CitizenIDP
    join tbCitizen c2 on d.CitizenIDF = c2.CitizenIDP
```